# field_discarded_type_conversion_failed error - pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am working on CROSS operator.I have two files data1 & data2 in hdfs as below.

data1-

```
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
```

data2

```
(2,4)
(8,9)
(1,3)
```

Now I am loading this file into a variable by typing command;

```
A = LOAD 'data1' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);
dump A;
```

After dumping it is showing error

> **FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED**

and showing like below;

```
(,,,)  
(,,,)
(,,,)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the load statement to use PigStorage with ',' as delimiter.

```
A = LOAD 'data1' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);
DUMP A;
```